# Are there any technical reasons why Monero Classic could not exist?

Tags: hard-fork, monero-forks

Assuming there were some people who did not like the Monero change from one to two minute blocks.

Are there any technical reasons they could have not just continued to mine on the old chain (with 1 minute blocks), call it Monero classic (XMC) and start trading it?

If Monero classic still is operational (is actively mined) why have I never heard of it? What makes ETC so much well known than the "losing" chain that resulted from Monero forks (LMDB fork, tail emission fork, etc)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No reason. Some did just that (probably not intentionally, though). You're free to mine on that chain, I think it's still there. You could make an exchange and sell those monero if you wished (assuming you find buyers).

The reason ETC kept going strong is that the ETH fork chose to reach back and blacklist some transactions or outputs (I don't know the details), rather than fix or improve something.